# Trouble formatting images in my CSS

Tags: css

community!
I am having trouble getting the formatting down for a few images I have.

**HTML**

```
<footer>
    <section class="socialmedia">
        <a href=""><img src="facebook.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="twitter.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" class="sm"></a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.sm {
    display: block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
    float: left;
    width: 2%;
}
```

The images are just lined up vertically to the left of the page, all at the original size. To my understanding the

> float: left;

is used to make them horizontal?

Also I would like them to be centered on the page, but margin: auto; is not changing anything either.

**EDIT**: I would like to have some spacing between each image as well, is there an alternative to

> & nbsp;

Comment: You're applying the styles to the wrong class. Not `.socialmedia` needs to `float`, but `.sm`. Also, you're making `.socialmedia` only `2%` wide, so the images have no choice but lining up vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do this (no need float and left property):

```css
img.sm {
  max-width:30px;
  width:100%;
  margin:5px;
}

/* Add a hover effect */

img.sm:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section class="socialmedia">
    <a href=""><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="sm"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class="sm"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="https://lorempixel.com/150/150/" class="sm"></a>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! The images are still stacked vertically and I would like them to be all horizontally in a line. Including spacing between, I think I am missing a piece.

Comment: Now just the sizing issue, they are displayed as the original size (460px) I would like them more manageable like (30px). I suppose resizing the vector itself is better practice, but I like have detailed images

Comment: you can add `width:30px` to sm class ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't changing anything for me, even if I make the width: 30px they are still full size. :(

Comment: @KevinP. see if you have specifide widht and heigh inside the image tag ? you can aslo add `!imporant` to force values

Comment: Could it be I have:
`* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}`
`html, body {width:100%;height:100%}`
That is causing this?

Comment: @KevinP. no it's not this ... instead of `.sm` use `img.sm` instead, more specfic selector

Comment: That did the trick! Why would that have caused so many issues? Should I get in the habit of being as specific as possible?

Comment: @KevinP. yes specifity in CSS is important, you need to carefully choose the selector and be specific to avoid having other CSS conflict ;) As you may have another CSS with higher specifity that override your style

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I hope this will solve your issue.

```css
.sm {
    display: block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.socialmedia > a {
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<footer>
    <section class="socialmedia">
        <a href=""><img src="https://www.wired.com/images/icons/social-facebook-square-blue.svg" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://www.persianfootball.com/forums/images/BP-White/misc/icon-twitter.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://www.downvids.net/images/inslogo.png" class="sm"></a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your styles to this:

```
/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You are applying the wrong properties on the wrong classes.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a float :) https://jsfiddle.net/L5eyd4bv/1/

```
.sm {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Using `text-align` on the parent element allows you to simply use `display: inline-block;`.

I have also put the class `.sm` on your `<a>` elements to facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you want the images to be side-by-side, but you're using the `float` on the `.socialmedia` element, which is the container and not the images. So you should change your CSS to:

```
.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
}
.socialmedia img {
    float: left;
}
```

```css
.sm {
    display: block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
}

.socialmedia img {
    float: left;
}

img {
   border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <section class="socialmedia">
        <a href=""><img src="facebook.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="twitter.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" class="sm"></a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

Here you have it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7j68Lvf/

If you want some space between the images, you can use `margin`, like this:

```
.socialmedia img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```css
.sm {
    display: block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
}

.socialmedia img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

img {
   border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <section class="socialmedia">
        <a href=""><img src="facebook.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="twitter.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" class="sm"></a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

Here you have it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7j68Lvf/1/

Now, for centering, you could give the `.socialmedia` element some width, and then use `margin: auto` on it, like this:

```
.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.sm {
    display: block;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.socialmedia {
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.socialmedia img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

img {
   border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <section class="socialmedia">
        <a href=""><img src="facebook.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="twitter.png" class="sm"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" class="sm"></a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

And here you have the whole thing in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7j68Lvf/2/

Answer (score 1):

What makes it horizontal is display:block

you can use the following code.

the "text-align" will locate the elements in the center.

for spacing use margin or padding.

```
.socialmedia {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sm {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

/* Add a hover effect */
.sm:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to take care of the issue with the sizing, all images still appear full size (460px). I suppose I will just resize them and save them smaller.

Comment: @KevinP. 
May be you have another style on "img" or smthn... (which is not the best practice)
But still you can force the current style by writing: "width: 50px !important;".
I'll update the code above.

Comment: The issue lied in not describing the selector enough, after changing .sm to .img sm - it solved the issue.